# 400 Bad Request while interception a request

Tags: burp

So I am using a burp suite to intercept a request to

```
stage.training.com/ats/getAllStates.html?countryCode=CR
```

Once Intercepted I change the Hostname to `localhost:4502`

The localhost uses an authentication which I have already added to Platform Authentication under

```
User Options -->  Platform Authentication
```

However I keep getting a 400 Bad Request response.
Any idea whats going wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we need to understand why **400 Http Bad Request** is causing the response.

> **400 - Bad request.** The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client should not repeat the request without modifications.

## You can check the following operations from inside the burp suite for authentication.

> 1. User options > Connections > Platform Authentication > Add
> 2. Destination host: target URL
> 3. Authentication type: Basic, NTLMv1, NTLMv2 or Digest
> 4. Username and Password

**Both sides need updating. from both intercept and user options. Otherwise, you will continue to receive errors.**